# Humanizr.net ignore word/acronym

Tags: .net, humanizer

I am looping through a collection of strings and using Humanizr.net.

This is so that I can correct each string to sentence case.

For example.

```
        List<string> mystrings = new List<string>();
        mystrings.Add("my string one");
        mystrings.Add("my string two aBC");
        mystrings.Add("My String Three");

        foreach (string x in mystrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Humanize());
        }
```

The output I am getting is this

```
        //what i am getting
        //----------------------
        //My string one
        //My string two a BC
        //My string three
```

I am wondering is it possible to add exclusions or words to ignore so that I get this

```
        //what i want
        //----------------------
        //My string two aBC
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lieu of a answer I have come up with the following solution.

1. Have a data store either Database or a Simple File (this is what i used in my case) that contains a list of know  words and acronyms that I don't want Humanizer to convert along with what Humanizer converts it to.
2. I then do a simple lookup and replace after the Humanizer call.

While not the most elegant solution it will work in my case for now.